# nginx serving static files; apache django; secure file from apache to nginx?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, django

I serve all static files (/static/ and /media/) via nginx and all other requests are routed to apache using mod_wsgi to use django. nginx acts as proxy through to Apache/mod_wsgi. As far as I know this is the recommended way, that one static files should be served separately.

Now I have the following situation, a user wants to download a file, but I need first to check if the user is allowed to download this file (which is not on /static/ neither /media/, obviously, else it would be public). This means the request has to go first to django. I suppose the recommended practice here is to -not- let apache serve the file, so if the user is authorized to download the file, is there anyway I can tell apache to use nginx to serve this file?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't need to use both nginx and apache. One of them is enough and can do both static and dynamic content properly. I'd advise nginx because of part two of your question.

If you want django-based access control on your files, use [X-SendFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296642/django-understanding-x-sendfile) to tell tell the webserver which file to serve.

Comment: I followed django's docs: "We recommend using a separate Web server – i.e., one that’s not also running Django – for serving media."
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/modpython/#serving-media-files

Comment: That's for mod_python deployment and a very old version of the docs.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ The statement is still there.

Comment: @Michael, "Django’s primary deployment platform is WSGI, the Python standard for web servers and applications.", so I'm using apache+modwsgi. I also posted a link about mod_wsgi, the statement about having a separate web server is the same.

Comment: @Clash OK, so you use nginx and you're covered. There's no reason to _keep_ Apache in this scenario.

Comment: @Michael, well, I'm no sysadmin so I'm not going to try to remove apache and make nginx do all the work. Considering nginx is the reverse proxy, do you know the answer to my question? Can I tell apache to use nginx to serve a file?

Comment: no. Apache doesn't know there's another layer above it.

Comment: @kormoc, I thought when nginx is the reverse proxy it still receives the response and can process the x-sendfile header?

Comment: That's not apache, that would be django instructing nginx to replace the request contents. Apache would be sending what it believes is the final page. That page may have the X-SendFile header which nginx intercepts, but apache doesn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

Because nginx is the reverse proxy, it actually receives the response before sending it to the user. I set manually the X-Accel-Redirect header from django and it worked flawlessly just like I wanted. http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile